# Draw a backwards link/pointer in a tree using the forest package

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I have been trying several things for a while but I am unable to find a working solution.

Let's say I have this pretty simple tree built using the forest package:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw,s sep=0.8cm}
[$\lambda$
    [,{edge label={node[midway,left] {B}}},{text=white,fill=black}
        [,{edge label={node[midway,left] {A}}}
            [,{edge label={node[midway,left] {B}}}
                [,{edge label={node[midway,left] {A}}},
                {text=white,fill=black}]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [,{edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}}
        [,{edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}},
            {text=white,fill=black}
            [,{edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}},
            {text=white,fill=black}]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Tree 1]

I would like to draw a backwards arrow between two nodes in separate branches. Is it even possible using the forest package (because it technically won't be a tree anymore)?

[image: Tree 2]

(Sorry about my English.)

Comment: Please always post code we can compile (or can try to compile if you want help solving a compilation error) as it makes things much clearer and easier! (That is, you are more likely to get more and higher quality answers this way.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can give a `name` to the nodes and then use regular TikZ drawing commands to connect them. You need to wrap the TikZ commands in braces to protect them from the `forest` bracket parser:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle,draw,s sep=0.8cm}
[$\lambda$
    [,{edge label={node[midway,left] {B}}},{text=white,fill=black}
        [,{edge label={node[midway,left] {A}}}
            [,{edge label={node[midway,left] {B}}}
                [,name=A2,{edge label={node[midway,left] {A}}},
                {text=white,fill=black}]
            ]
        ]
    ]
    [,name=A1,{edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}}
        [,{edge label={node[midway,right] {B}}},
            {text=white,fill=black}
            [,{edge label={node[midway,right] {A}}},
            {text=white,fill=black}]
        ]{\draw[->] (A2) .. controls +(right:1) and +(left:1) .. (A1);}
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @waran Too much typing! (+1 obviously)

Answer (score 6):

Here's an adaptation of [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335244/) which may be of interest if you don't like typing or need to draw lots of trees in this style.

I define the the tree styles `labelled tree` and `circle tree` for use in the preamble of trees.

`labelled tree` activates a style which allows you to specify

```
<content>:<edge label>
```

as the node's content and have the edge label automatically positioned to the left or the right.

`circle tree` just makes the nodes circles etc.

In addition, `inverse` sets the text to white and the fill to black.

Finally, `arrow to` is a style which takes three arguments.

```
arrow to={<first control point>}{<second control point>}{<node to connect to>}
```

This allows you to specify the connector as an option to the node from which the connection should be drawn. The node to connect to may be specified either using a relative node name (e.g. `!r2` in this example) or using a label specified with `name` (as in Alan's answer).

This means that we can draw Alan's tree using the following code.

```
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [:B, inverse
      [:A
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!r2}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [:A
      [:B, inverse
        [:A, inverse
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: labelled circle tree]

More generally,

```
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [:B, inverse
      [:A
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!r2}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [:A
      [:B, inverse
        [:A, inverse
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [:B, inverse
      [:A
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={left:1}{left:1}{!r1}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [:B, inverse
      [:A
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!r2}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [:A
      [:B, inverse
        [:A, inverse
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [:B
      [:A, inverse
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={left:1}{right:1}{!r2}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [$\omega$
      [:B, inverse
        [:A
          [:B
            [:A
              [:B, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!uuu2}
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [:A
             [:B
              [:A, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!r12}
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [:A
        [:B, inverse
          [:A, inverse
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [:B
        [:A, inverse
          [:B
            [:A, inverse, arrow to={left:1}{right:1}{!r12}
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

produces

[image: generalised case]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare boolean register=sloped labels,
  not sloped labels,
  my edge label/.style={
    tempcountc/.option=grow,
    if reversed={
      tempcountc-/.register=tempcountb,
    }{
      tempcountc+/.register=tempcountb,
    },
    if sloped labels={
      temptoksa=sloped,
    }{
      temptoksa=,
    },
    edge label/.expanded={node [midway, shift=(\foresteregister{tempcountc}:10pt), \foresteregister{temptoksa}] {#1}}
  },
  labelled tree/.style={
    before typesetting nodes={
      where={(n_children())>1}{
        tempcounta/.pgfmath={int(((n_children())+1)/2)},
        if={isodd(n_children())}{
          for n/.wrap pgfmath arg={{##1}{calign with current}}{(tempcounta)},
        }{},
        for nodewalk={
          n=1,
          filter={current and siblings}{n()<(tempcounta)},
        }{
          for nodewalk={
            c,
            while={int(n_children())==1}{
              on invalid={fake}{n=1},
            }{},
          }{
            tempcountb'=-90,
            split option={content}{:}{content,my edge label},
          },
        },
        for nodewalk={
          n'=1,
          filter={current and siblings}{n()>=(tempcounta)},
        }{
          for nodewalk={
            c,
            while={int(n_children())==1}{
              on invalid={fake}{n=1},
            }{},
          }{
            tempcountb'=-270,
            split option={content}{:}{content,my edge label},
          },
        },
      }{},
      for nodewalk={
        fake=r,
        while={int(n_children())==1}{
          on invalid={fake}{n=1},
        }{},
      }{
        tempcountb'=-270,
        split option={content}{:}{content,my edge label},
      },
    },
  },
  arrow to/.style n args=3{
    tikz+={
      \draw [->] () .. controls +(#1) and +(#2) .. (#3);
    }
  },
  inverse/.style={text=white, fill=black},
  circle tree/.style={
    for tree={
      circle,
      draw,
      s sep=0.8cm,
      edge={->},
    },
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [:B, inverse
      [:A
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!r2}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [:A
      [:B, inverse
        [:A, inverse
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [:B, inverse
      [:A
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={left:1}{left:1}{!r1}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [:B, inverse
      [:A
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!r2}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [:A
      [:B, inverse
        [:A, inverse
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [:B
      [:A, inverse
        [:B
          [:A, inverse, arrow to={left:1}{right:1}{!r2}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  labelled tree,
  circle tree,
  [$\lambda$
    [$\omega$
      [:B, inverse
        [:A
          [:B
            [:A
              [:B, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!uuu2}
              ]
            ]
          ]
          [:A
             [:B
              [:A, inverse, arrow to={right:1}{left:1}{!r12}
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [:A
        [:B, inverse
          [:A, inverse
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [:B
        [:A, inverse
          [:B
            [:A, inverse, arrow to={left:1}{right:1}{!r12}
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I bow to your superior `forest` fu. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm a fiddler .... Please see edited answer above.

Comment: @waran If you use this, please note that I've updated the code above to make it a bit more robust.

Comment: Thank you. :) I have used the original answer by Alan Munn, because it was easier for me to implement into existing code. But I am pretty sure that I will need to do something similar in some point and I will probably use your solution, because it's more synoptic for larger graphs. :)